BPY toggle viewport visibility of modifiers
I want to save the dimensions of an object in a script before and after the viewport visibility for the modifiers has been switched off.
 for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
            
            # Get the selected object
            selected_object = bpy.context.active_object

            filled_x    =   obj.dimensions.x
            filled_y    =   obj.dimensions.y
            filled_z    =   obj.dimensions.z

            # Temporarily disable the array modifier
            bpy.context.selected_objects.modifiers.show_viewport = False

            unfilled_x    =   obj.dimensions.x
            unfilled_y    =   obj.dimensions.y
            unfilled_z    =   obj.dimensions.z

            # Calculating dimensions as specified, rounding up
            dimX = math.ceil(filled_x / unfilled_x)
            dimY = math.ceil(filled_y / unfilled_y)
            dimZ = math.ceil(filled_z / unfilled_z)

This is my very basic code to try and do this. But the viewport visibility of the modifiers is still on.
What would be my best solution to try and fix this problem?

this is one of the questions, i am asking myself: did you just spent 3 minutes on it or less? Did you run your code at all? or just asked chatgpt and copied it here? If you run this, you will get an error, it says: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'modifiers'. So it should be clear, the selected_objects (which is plural) is a list, and multiple objects of course don't have modifiers, because exact one object just has a modifier.

keep in mind: you want help for free in our spare time - so you should at least spend 5 mins with this question and have at least the code run one time before asking. Thanks.

Hello, as Chris mentioned this line bpy.context.selected_objects.modifiers.show_viewport = False is where the problem lies, but it's impossible to fix without further info from your part. it mentions the array modifier but we need to know either its name or its location from within the modifier list

    for obj in bpy.context.selected_objects:
        
        # Get the selected object
        #selected_object = bpy.context.active_object 
# you don't need to get the selected object, because you are already looping over them, so the "obj" is (!) your first selected object

        filled_x    =   obj.dimensions.x
        filled_y    =   obj.dimensions.y
        filled_z    =   obj.dimensions.z

        # Temporarily disable the array modifier
        # bpy.context.selected_objects.modifiers.show_viewport = False
        # selected_objects is a list. Lists don't have a property modifiers. A single object can have modifiers. So you could get the first modifier and set the show_viewport there.

        obj.modifiers[0].show_viewport = False

        unfilled_x    =   obj.dimensions.x
        unfilled_y    =   obj.dimensions.y
        unfilled_z    =   obj.dimensions.z

        # Calculating dimensions as specified, rounding up
        dimX = math.ceil(filled_x / unfilled_x)
        dimY = math.ceil(filled_y / unfilled_y)
        dimZ = math.ceil(filled_z / unfilled_z)

This will help you, but i would recommend watching some beginner python and Blender API tutorials.
And my "correction" is far from being perfect.
you should

ask whether a modifier is there at all (else my code will crash)
add another loop over the modifiers inside your loop so you can disable all modfiers

